# Why isn't the size increase animating with ngShow (angularjs)?

Tags: css, angularjs, less, css-animations

I have this dropdown that I want the height to be animated. I'm using max-height to achieve this and it kinda works, but when it expands it won't do the transition. If I reduce the size (i.e. go back) then it transitions just fine.

I have this [pen](https://codepen.io/LoyalPotato/pen/wvywPRK) with the html and css (less) that I'm using. The animations aren't working there but the code is the same as what I have in the next gif.

[image: Gif]

The contents of the first menu are "dynamic" as in they can be either 1, 2 or 3, hence the different heights that I have defined with different classes.

Here is the css:

```
.content-management-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem !important;
  top: 2;
  right: 2.5rem;
  width: 17rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.6rem 1.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;

  .menu-primary {
    width: 100%;

    &.ng-hide-remove {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(-110%);
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove-active {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
      // max-height: 3.7rem;

      // &.menu-2-item {
      //   max-height: calc(3.7rem * 2);
      // }

      // &.menu-3-item {
      //   max-height: calc(3.7rem * 3);
      // }
    }

    &.ng-hide-add {
      position: absolute;
      max-height: 3.7rem;
      &.menu-2-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 2);
      }

      &.menu-3-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 3);
      }
    }

    &.ng-hide-add-active {
      transform: translateX(-110%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
      max-height: 27rem;
    }
  }

  .menu-secondary {
    &.ng-hide-remove {
      transform: translateX(110%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove-active {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add {
      max-height: 27rem;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add-active {
      transform: translateX(110%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;

      max-height: 3.7rem;

      &.menu-2-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 2) !important;
      }

      &.menu-3-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 3) !important;
      }
    }
  }

  ul {
    padding: 0;
  }

  &__list-item {
    padding: 0.6rem 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid black;
    transition: background 500ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    & > * {
      display: block;
      padding: 0.3rem 2rem;
      text-transform: none !important;
    }

    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: #edf1f5;
    }
  }
}
```

I also was using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA) video as reference for the animations.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up figuring it out.
I changed the css and the secondary menu is the only one that controls the heights. Then I had an issue with the heights and it turns out one of the heights was just being overwritten with a smaller height.

Here is the final css for the menus:

```css
.menu-primary {
    width: 100%;

    &.ng-hide-remove {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(-110%);
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove-active {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add {
      position: absolute;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add-active {
      transform: translateX(-110%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
    }
  }

  .menu-secondary {

    &.ng-hide-remove {
      transform: translateX(110%);
      max-height: 3.7rem;

      &.menu-2-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 2);
      }

      &.menu-3-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 3);
      }
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove-active {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;
      max-height: 27rem !important;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add {
      max-height: 27rem;
    }

    &.ng-hide-add-active {
      transform: translateX(110%);
      transition: all 500ms ease;

      max-height: 3.7rem;

      &.menu-2-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 2);
      }

      &.menu-3-item {
        max-height: calc(3.7rem * 3);
      }
    }
```